# RStudio converted code to jibberish, froze, and saved as gibberish

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, memory, rstudio

I had a small but important R file that I have been working on for a few days.

I created and uploaded a list of about 1,000 ID's to SQL Server the other day and today I was repeating the process with a different type of ID. I frequently save the file and after having added a couple of lines and saved, I ran the `sqlSave()` statement to upload the new ID's.

RStudio promptly converted all of my code to gibberish and froze (see screen shot).

[image]

After letting it try to finish for several minutes I closed RStudio and reopened it. It automatically re-opened my untitled text files where I had a little working code, but didn't open my main code file.

When I tried to open it I was informed that the file is 55 Megabytes and thus too large to open. Indeed, I confirmed that it really is 55MB now and when opening it in an external text editor I see the same gibberish as in this screnshot.

Is there any hope of recovering my code?

I suppose a low memory must be to blame. The object and command I was executing at the time were not resource intensive, however a few minutes before that I did retrieve an overly large dataframe from SQL Server.

Comment: I hope for your sake that I'm wrong about this, but I think you overwrote your code with a binary representation of your objects! `save.image` might not do what you think it does. It *saves the R objects* not your R script file. What you have done is overwritten your R script file with a binary representation of your objects. To save your script, you can just click "File->Save". To save your objects, you would have to put that in a different file.

Comment: What SQL package are you using? That is, what package does `sqlSave` come from?   (RODBC?)  .  Unless you specified something creative like `.Rdata` as the file in your `sqlSave` call, there "shouldn't" be any way to bork your data file.   I don't suppose you have a backup of your `R` -related files (next time you will  :-(  )

Comment: The hypothesis by @nograpes makes sense.  The console history shows you used `save.image("jive.R")`.  It seems you wrote your data file over the script file.  With a bit of luck you have enabled automatic saving of your command history in RStudio and somewhere in your system you still have an .RData file with your history.  Good luck.

Comment: I only wish that I overwrote it with binary... I could fix that. Using Cygwin to get a linux shell within Windows 7 I used the commands base64 and hexdump to try converting it from binary to text, but it didn't result in a sensible text file.  Carl: It was RODBC. I did have version control enabled but apparently it was also damaged when this happened and I can't view my prior commits.

Comment: Oh, you're right (nograpes and Andrie)! I see what you're saying now! I meant to type ".Rdata" not ".R"! Well that sucks for me, but feel free to make that into an official answer if you want.

Comment: @Andrie That should be an `.RHistory` file should it not, or is RStudio different from normal R in this regard?

Comment: @NerdLife thats a tough break. Have a look at using git with your RStudio workflow. It would prevent such problems moving forward.

Comment: I used version control and checked RHistory but no luck. Thanks for the ideas tho. Someone should post @nograpes comment as an answer or kill this post hopefully without hurting my rep too much. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote your code with a binary representation of your objects with this line:

```
save.image('jive.R')
```

`save.image`  saves the R objects, not your R script file. To save your script, you can just click "File->Save". To save your objects, you would have to put that in a different file.

Comment: Thanks, nograpes. I sure do feel silly. It was just a typo, but *WHAT* a typo!